# Offered to review a low quality question after flagging it for closure

Tags: bug, review, low-quality-posts

I saw [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1629370/why-is-the-pr%C3%BCfer-sequence-in-a-labeled-tree-always-unique) just when it was asked, and instantly flagged this as off-topic.

But, before sometime, someone flagged this as low-quality post, and it was sent to me for review. And then when I clicked the button *recommend close*, it showed me *You flagged this question for closure 57 mins ago*. So, the only option left for me is to skip that review, because *looks ok* is totally ridiculous.

So, my question is why this question was sent in my queue? Is not it like forcing me to skip this review. I just don't want to skip this particular review.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with skipping reviews. You don't have to review everything.

Comment: Weird: [The Review protocol](http://math.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/565254) says you have reviewed it. (And as Asaf said, there's nothing wrong with skipping reviews. On the contrary, it's a good thing. Nobody always knows what is the right thing.)

Comment: @DanielFischer, ok then, why this was sent in my queue. It is not rebarbative and annoying, when you see that a flag is waiting for review in your queue and when you open this, you see that you have to skip this(forcefully)? And [see this](http://math.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/565309), It is still in my queue, as if it is waiting for my review!

Comment: I would think that now, you will see "This item is no longer reviewable." at that review item, the question is closed. But anyway, there's something strange going on, you should not see review items you can't act on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the handling of already-flagged questions in Low Quality Queue needs some attention from a developer. This issue was reported in 2013: [Low Quality Posts you Have Already Flagged](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/193128), and acknowledged by an employee back then:

> Existing logic prevents you from seeing a post you've voted to close, but ignores flags (mostly). I guess I can't think of a good reason to have you reviewing a post you've already flagged though, regardless of the type of flag

Still not fixed, though.

A workaround is to reach 3000 reputation points. There's an excellent chance you'll get there sooner than this bug is fixed.